# HTML Progressbar starts loading wrong with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying out some animation with the progress tag in html combined with javascript and jquery.

As far as it goes now my progress bar loads from my value to 100% and it should go from 0 to my given value with the max of the bar being 100.

I tried this with the following site but i cant find what i did different.
http://html5doctor.com/the-progress-element/

Codepen of my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNQjBL

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Photoshop</h2>
    <h4>Kanalen</h4>
    <progress id="progressbar" value="22" max="100">
    </progress>
    <span class="progress-value">22%</span>
    <h4>Kanalen</h4>
    <progress value="56" max="100">
    </progress>
    <h4>Kanalen</h4>
    <progress value="83" max="100">
    </progress>
    <h4>Kanalen</h4>
    <progress value="15" max="100">
    </progress>
</div>
```

scripting code;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!Modernizr.meter) {
        alert('Sorry your brower does not support HTML5 progress bar');
    } else {
        var progressbar = $('#progressbar')
            , max = progressbar.attr('max')
            , time = (1000 / max) * 5
            , value = progressbar.val();

        var loading = function () {
            value += 1;
            addValue = progressbar.val(value);

            $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

            if (value == max) {
                clearInterval(animate);
            }
        };

        var animate = setInterval(function () {
            loading();
        }, time);
    };
});
```

I added some code of my project above;

Comment: it looks like its working fine in your codepen.

Comment: @reddy Im trying to make it animate to my value now its static :-)

Comment: [Removing all of the crap in your Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVYLBd) makes it work just fine.

Comment: Also, removing the `if(!Modernizr.meter)` check fixes it too - the console clearly says "Modernizr is undefined" =/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Hello! I am aware that it animates the bar but i want it to stop at a given value like 22%. So you see a bar and it gets filled for 22% (animated) and then it stops. With the remaining 78% still the gray bar.

Comment: Oh I see. But your code is all about starting at the value and proceeding to `max`. It's simple: set your starting value to `0` and the "max" (ie. the target) to the existing `value`. [Like so](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNQMeL)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Super! Thanks for helping out